# Combining Update & Select SQL statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

MS Access VBA Scripts that create SQL Statements:

I have a SQL Statement that derives two fields in a new table SATable:

```
SQLScript = "SELECT [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].* INTO SATable"
SQLScript = SQLScript & " FROM [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]"
SQLScript = SQLScript & " WHERE ((([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]) In (SELECT [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]"
SQLScript = SQLScript & " FROM [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]"
SQLScript = SQLScript & " GROUP BY [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]"
SQLScript = SQLScript & " HAVING (((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))=" & Chr(34) & "Navy" & Chr(34) & ") AND ((Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))=" & Chr(34) & "USMC" & Chr(34) & ")) OR (((First([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))=" & Chr(34) & "USMC" & Chr(34) & ") AND ((Last([DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch))=" & Chr(34) & "Navy" & Chr(34) & "));)));"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLScript
```

Then I have a statement that takes those two derived fields and appends them onto the original table:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE SATable INNER JOIN [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] ON (SATable.[Journal Voucher ID] = [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Journal Voucher ID]) AND (SATable.dBranch = [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].dBranch) SET [DATA OUTPUT TABLE].[Shared Appropriations] = [SATable].[dBranch] & " & Chr(34) & " Shared Appropriation" & Chr(34) & ";"
```

My goal is to remove the SATable and perform this action in one statement.

I've struggled with problems like this before so instead of just providing an answer can you please provide some explanation - TEACH A MAN TO FISH!

Cheers,
-E

EDIT:-------------------------------------------------------------
The Data Output Table has:

```
JVID dBranch SA
   1  Navy   N/A
   2  Navy   N/A
   3  Navy   N/A
   4  Navy   N/A
   A  USMC   N/A
   B  USMC   N/A
   3  USMC   N/A
   4  USMC   N/A
```

So the SATable becomes:

```
JVID dBranch SA
   3  Navy   Navy SA
   3  USMC   USMC SA
   4  Navy   Navy SA
   4  USMC   USMC SA
```

Then the update query updates the SA field, which is N/A by default

```
JVID dBranch SA
   1  Navy   N/A
   2  Navy   N/A
   3  Navy   Navy SA
   4  Navy   Navy SA
   A  USMC   N/A
   B  USMC   N/A
   3  USMC   USMC SA
   4  USMC   USMC SA
```

Comment: I suspect you might be able to simplify the SQL a bit.  I think it would help if you show the tables with example data, and the expected output.

Comment: I can't share data, but I'll expand on the intent

Comment: So, you want to select out of the [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] and into [SATable] (having the results in your third table) in one step?  Or do you want the update to happen to the [DATA OUTPUT TABLE]?

Comment: @WyattEarp (Great Name) I want to skip the helper table SATable, and update the SA field in the Data Output Table directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I might be making an assumption or two, but it looks like what you really want to do is to join `[DATA OUTPUT TABLE]` (`@tDataOutputTable` in my script) on itself (similar to what you're doing) and only update records that match on `JVIDs`, but not `dBranch`

Now, this will match any record where the `dBranch` columns don't match.  If you only want this to happen for dBranch of 'Navy' and 'USMC', then you'll want to replace my `d.dBranch <> d2.dBranch` with something more like what you have.

Here is a SQL script that I created to test it:

```
DECLARE @tDataOutputTable TABLE
(
    JVID varchar(max),
    dBranch varchar(max),
    SA varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @tDataOutputTable (JVID, dBranch, SA)
VALUES 
('1', 'Navy', 'N/A'),
('2', 'Navy', 'N/A'),
('3', 'Navy', 'N/A'),
('4', 'Navy', 'N/A'),
('A', 'USMC', 'N/A'),
('B', 'USMC', 'N/A'),
('3', 'USMC', 'N/A'),
('4', 'USMC', 'N/A')

UPDATE d
    SET d.SA = d.dBranch + ' SA' -- or 'Shared Appropriation'
FROM @tDataOutputTable d
    INNER JOIN @tDataOutputTable d2 ON d.JVID = d2.JVID AND d.dBranch <> d2.dBranch

SELECT * FROM @tDataOutputTable
```

I'm not that familiar with the intricacies of VBA and Access, but hopefully something like this should work:

```
SQLScript = "UPDATE [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] AS d"
SQLScript = SQLScript & " INNER JOIN [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] AS d2 ON d.JVID = d2.JVID AND d.dBranch <> d2.dBranch"
SQLScript = SQLScript & " SET d.SA = d.dBranch" & Chr(34) & " Shared Appropriation" & Chr(34) & ";"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLScript
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; That's at least partially correct.

I've seen SQL statements where a variable name is made and used like "d" in your code. How is that done?

My script uses the Group By & Having to get a record list of only the [JVID]s that have a [dbranch] of both Navy and USMC. Then, the update query joins on the [JVID] and makes the [SA] field update from N/A to [dbranch] + "SA"

Comment: @Schalton, Okay, I tried this in Access and have updated the code so that it should work.  Basically, rather than creating the SATable, we'll be joining [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] on itself, where the `JVID` matches and the `dBranch` doesn't.  ` AS d` is called an alias, and allows us to join the table on itself.

Comment: I'd never worked with an alias at the table level, only at the field level, that's great! Thanks!